# Looking for a geometric, straight font that packs a punch

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I'm looking for a fat, punch packing font that's very straight and geometric. it needs to accompany a font like https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/northernblock/borda/ , but have the thickness and presence of http://www.fontbureau.com/fonts/TitlingGothicFB/

Thanks for any recommendation you might have!

Comment: Hello and welcome, the reason you are being downvoted is that your question is way out of scope on many dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using illustrator or photoshop you can just download the borda font and then increase the stroke size